# How to change java.system.class.loader property?

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, ide, ubuntu-20.04

I am not able to launch intellij-idea due to this error on Ubuntu 20.04.

```html
<pre><font color="#4E9A06"><b>vaibhav@vaibhav-Inspiron-3543</b></font>:<font color="#3465A4"><b>~</b></font>$ intellij-idea-community 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Archived non-system classes are disabled because the java.system.class.loader property is specified (value = &quot;com.intellij.util.lang.PathClassLoader&quot;). To use archived non-system classes, this property must not be set
IDE has not been initialized yet
</pre>
```

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Archived non-system classes are disabled because the java.system.class.loader property is specified (value = "com.intellij.util.lang.PathClassLoader"). To use archived non-system classes, this property must not be set
IDE has not been initialized yet

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA needs Java 11 to run, please use JetBrains Runtime: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879.